# Concatenating columns' string values depending on the condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am concatenating three columns' values that are all formatted as str to be able to get the full address. The first one is the unit number, and some properties do not have a unit number, so I would like to not concatenate the unit number value for those where it's missing. How do I add the if statement?

```
df['address_original'] = df['unit_number'].str.cat(df[['street_number', 'street_name']], 
                                                   sep=', ')
print df['address_original'][:5]


0                 , 184, VEALE ROAD
1                 , 124, VEALE ROAD
2    , 1068, CLEARWATER VALLEY ROAD
3               , 1605, PINE STREET
4         , 1425, LOPEZ CREEK DRIVE
Name: address_original, dtype: object
```

Here's the original dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=search_results1)
print df.info()
print type(df)

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2619 entries, 0 to 2618
Columns: 111 entries, access to zoning
dtypes: object(111)
memory usage: 2.2+ MB
None
```

Here's currently what's in address_original column

```
print df['address_original'][:3]
0                 , 184, VEALE ROAD
1                 , 124, VEALE ROAD
2    , 1068, CLEARWATER VALLEY ROAD
Name: address_original, dtype: object
```

Comment: Please post reproducible sample of your original datset

Comment: try to use numpy where, `np.where`

Comment: @PV8 Here's what I tried to do: `df['address_original'] = (
    np.where(
        df['unit_number'].notna, str(df['unit_number']) + ', '+str(df['street_number'])+ ', '+str(df['street_name'],)
        np.where(df['unit_number'].isna, str(df['street_number'])+ ', '+
                 str(df['street_name'])))
    

print df['address_original'][:3]`

Comment: @PV8 and the result I got was: `np.where(df['unit_number'].isna, str(df['street_number'])+ ', '+
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Where did I mess up?

Comment: sorry, but could you add the original dataframe and the target oclumn to your post? just two-three rows, to get an idea what oyu want to do

Comment: @PV8 let me know if it's good now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it then?

```
df['address_original'] = np.where(df['unit_number'].isnull(), df['street_number'].astype(str)+','+df['street_name'].astype(str), df['unit_Number'].astype(str)+','+df['street_number'].astype(str)+','+df['street_name'].astype(str))
```

I am still not sure how your target column should look like

Comment: that's correct, its coming up with a mistake when I run your code though `TypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('S32') dtype('S32') dtype('S32')`

Answer (score 2):

Try this, may this helps you

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


data = pd.read_csv('c.csv')
print(data)

def GetFullAddress(unitno, add1, add2):
    print(unitno, add1, add2)
    sunitno = ''
    if(unitno>0):
        sunitno = str(unitno)+', '

    return sunitno + add1 + ', '+add2

data['address'] = data.apply(lambda row: GetFullAddress(row['unitno'],row['add1'],row['add2']))
print(data)
```

**Used data is:**

```
   unitno         add1         add2
0       0  'address11'  'address21'
1      12  'address12'  'address22'
2       0  'address13'  'address23'
3      14  'address14'  'address24'
4       0  'address15'  'address25'
```

Comment: does that mean I would have to replace df['street_number'] with a variable street_number? It won't allow me to define the function with columns from the dataframe

Comment: its also not letting me geocode the resulting address, giving the following mistake: TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: You also need to give `index=1` in apply arguments